# Shall I use singleton or @environment?

Tags: swiftui, binding, environment

In SwiftUI, I need to create a `var x: Int`, to store sum of calculations done in a couple of views one by one. This var should be taken as an entry point to continue some additional calculations in the next view, and so on. I can not use `@binding`, as it does not work as an entry to continue calculations from the next view. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don’t you declare it as ‘@State’ in the first view and then ‘@Binding’ further down?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better understand how to post a good question in this community.

Comment: I intend to use a couple of views with each one adding new values so the sum is to be displayed; @Binding ties up only two views. Or so I think.